# How to Cancel a remote shutdown with windows command prompt

Tags: windows-7, remote-shutdown

I am playing around with the cmd application and have been using the following to shutdown pc's remotely.

C:\Users\account1>shutdown -r -f -m \testpc -t 60

My question is, how can I cancel command once I've started it(within the 60 seconds).

Comment: Try `shutdown /?` to view the help....

Answer (score 1):

The -a argument cancels a scheduled shutdown.